# MySQL Procedure variable receiving null on count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

Why when I do `Select count(*) From table1` I receive 300 but if I do `SELECT end = COUNT(*) FROM table1;` returns null

Here is the fiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/ZHzoaztV

code snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  start int NOT NULL,
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  counter int NOT NULL,
  difference int NOT NULL,
  end int NOT NULL
);

CREATE PROCEDURE doWhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE start INT DEFAULT 120;
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE end INT DEFAULT 300;
WHILE (i <= end) DO
  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (start,null,counter,start+counter,end); 
  SET i = i+1;
  SET counter = counter+1;
END WHILE;
END;
CALL doWhile();
SELECT * FROM table1;


CREATE PROCEDURE insertMore()
BEGIN
  DECLARE start INT;
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE end INT;

  SELECT end = COUNT(*) FROM table1;
  SELECT start = MAX(id)+1 FROM table1;
  -- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1;

  WHILE (counter <= end) DO
    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (start,null,counter,start+counter,end); 
    SET counter = counter+1;
  END WHILE;
END;
CALL insertMore();
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

I expected to return 300, so hopefully my function should do it right

Comment: use: `SELECT count(*) into end from table1;`  Probably  [end](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-E:~:text=ENCRYPTION-,END,-ENDS) should be enclosed in back-ticks, because it's a reserved word

Comment: @Luuk yet did not work https://dbfiddle.uk/Yypa52Wo

Comment: Please define "did not work", see: https://dbfiddle.uk/69v7FP9e

Comment: @Luuk I changed to end1 and still returning null, could you try make it work in fiddle please?

Comment: see 2 mins ago ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with start and end Variable

Can you try this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertMore()
BEGIN
  DECLARE start INT;
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE end INT;

  SELECT COUNT(*) into end FROM table1;
  SELECT max(id)+1 into start FROM table1;
  -- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1;

  WHILE (counter <= end) DO
    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (start,null,counter,start+counter,end); 
    SET counter = counter+1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

Try it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/X6vP3wKW

Comment: Great it does work, but is there a way to get it a better performance, instead of doing 2 Select queries? something SELECT max(id)+1 into start, COUNT(*) into end FROM table1;

Comment: Yes you can do it as follows : SELECT max(id)+1, COUNT(*) into start, end FROM table1;